# cost of a call to calculatematrix method

Tags: matrix

In terms of usage API is there diference between call n times a 1 X n calculatematrix and call 1 time a n x n calculatematrix?
For example, if I need a matrix of 3 origens and 3 destinations. Is there difference of cost if I call 3 times a calculatematrix with 1 origen and 3 destinations or I call one time a calculatematrix with 3 origens and 3 destinations?

Comment: Is this question tied to any programming language, or in general? Also, what do you mean exactly by "calculatematrix"? Apply a function to each cell? Get Eigen values? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: The language is indifferent. I am using a routing API of HERE.com. I request a Matrix of Routes like this:https://matrix.route.cit.api.here.com
/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json

Comment: What do you mean? You have 9 url's you want to connect to? I suggest you add you your post an example of a matrix, and how you use it, so hopefully someone can help. My guy feeling is it doesn't matter, but a concrete example will help.